# ALINK Error while Building the Solution in VS2012

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012

hi i'm getting a ALINK Build error while building the solution first time and every thing works fine second time.

```
Error   16  Metadata failure while creating assembly -- The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. 

C:\workspaces\ProjectPath\ALINK ProjectName
```

it only happens for the first time i'm not sure how to solve this issue.

Answer (score -2):

Open the project file and remove the  tag with newly included data or irrelevant to your project.
Clean the project and build the project.

Comment: @downvoters please leave a comment when downvoting new users.